Derivative: Product rule for vector-valued vector-input functions
From https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Multivariable_Calculus/Chain_Rule I get
$$
J_{\mathbf {p} }(\mathbf {f} \cdot \mathbf {g} ) = \mathbf {g} ^{T}J_{\mathbf {p} }\mathbf {f} +\mathbf {f} ^{T}J_{\mathbf {p} }\mathbf {g} \hspace{1cm} (1)
$$
where I understanding is that the

$f : R^m → R^{n}$
$g : R^m → R^{n}$
$\cdot$ is the dot product (inner product)

so we can rewrite
$$
J_{\mathbf {p} }(\mathbf {f}^T\mathbf {g} ) = \mathbf {g} ^{T}J_{\mathbf {p} }\mathbf {f} +\mathbf {f} ^{T}J_{\mathbf {p} }\mathbf {g} \hspace{1cm} (2)
$$
where $\mathbf {f}^T\mathbf {g}$ is the matrix product between $\mathbf {f}^T$ and $\mathbf {g}$.
If we substitute $\mathbf X := \mathbf {f}^T$ and $\mathbf Y := \mathbf {g}$ we get
$$
J_{\mathbf {p} }(\mathbf X\mathbf Y ) = \mathbf Y ^{T}J_{\mathbf {p} }\mathbf X^T +\mathbf XJ_{\mathbf {p} }\mathbf Y \hspace{1cm} (3)
$$
The matrix cookbook (https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) does not suggest to transpose anything:
$$
∂(\mathbf X\mathbf Y) = (∂\mathbf X)\mathbf Y + \mathbf X(∂\mathbf Y) \hspace{1cm} (37)
$$
Why is in (37) no transposition?
Is it wrong to interpret $∂$ as Jacobian in this case? Am I missing something else?

Looks just like the two authors are using different notation for the same / similar concepts. Note in the second situation one is using full blown matrix multiplication, Whereas in the former you are using vectors and dots. What is happening is in the first case transposes and dot products are being used as shims to convert concepts/notations about matrices (R^nxm objects) to that of column and row vectors (R^n).

@user2628206: I know that in the wikibook dot product is used an vectors and the matrixcookbook the matrix product and matrices are used. I took that into account and rewrote the formulas such that they become comparable. Why are (3) and (37) still different regarding the transposition?

Note that if you can prove that $g^TJ_p(f) = f^TJ_p(g)$ then you are done. Can you think of identities that allow you to achieve that result?

@user2628206: (1) Do you ask for which special $g$ and special $f$ the equation $g^T J_p(f) = f^T J_p(g)$ does hold? I don't know. (2) And I do not know how this is helping :-/. Afterall, I wanted to know the above for the general case as layed out. (3) Finally, even if this equation is true for the general case: Why would I be done?

Sorry I meant to write  $g^TJ_p(f)= J_p(f^T)g$ but had a brain fart (technically the transpose of but in the question some implicit transpose operations have been suppressed due to the spaces $R^{1 \times n}$, $R^{n \times 1}$ and $R^n$ being implicitly all identified together). I can go into more detain in a proper answer but to do it justice will take me some time to write out!

@user2628206: I do not see why $g^T J_p(f) = J_p(f^T)g$, amongst other things, because I do not see what $J_p$ of a row vector is supposed to be. I would agree that $g^T J_p(f) = ( J_p(f)^T g )^T$, but I do not see how this is would help. (Sorry, I am just an engineer.)

Ok I think I see the issue as a combination of notational choices in the question plus you being provided with a definition of the (multivariate) derivative / Jacobian that is more specialized than that which is currently needed to efficiently see how (37) and (1) equate.
I will write up an answer that hopefully makes this clear tonight. Just now that they are both correct, and the form of (37) is the more general definition, the one given in (1) works as a happy accident due to the specifics of the problem!

The simple answer is that the Jacobian is not $\partial$. Rather, the Jacobian is the "quotient" $J_{p}(f) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, where $x$ is the input to the function $f$.
The meaning of $\partial {f}$ is the difference $f(x+h) - f(x)$ for small $h$, which is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The meaning of $\partial {x}$ is $(x+h) - x = h$, which is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Strictly speaking, the "equation" $J_{p}(f) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is only a first order approximation, but all the "equations" given in the Matrix Cookbook that you linked are first order approximations, so I'll continue with this notation.
The correct way to relate the two equations is to start with your equation (2):
\begin{align}
J_p(f^{T}g) = g^{T}J_p(f) + f^{T}J_p(g).
\end{align}
Now rewrite all the Jacobians:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (f^{T}g)}{\partial x} = g^{T}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f^{T} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}.
\end{align}
You can "multiply" both sides by $\partial x$:
\begin{align}
\partial(f^{T}g) = g^{T}(\partial f) + f^{T}(\partial g).
\end{align}
Now, you should recall that $f$ and $g$ have the same dimension as vectors: they are both vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $\partial f$ and $\partial g$ are differences of $f$ and $g$ evaluated at nearby points, they are also vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore $g^{T}(\partial f)$ is a scalar (or a 1x1 matrix, depending on your point of view) and equals its transpose $(\partial f)^{T}g$.
Finally, $(\partial f)^{T}g = (f(x+h) - f(x))^{T}g = (f^{T}(x+h) - f^{T}(x))g = (\partial f^{T})g$. Plugging this into the last result gives:
\begin{align}
\partial(f^{T}g) = (\partial f^{T})g + f(\partial g).
\end{align}
This is the equation without transposes, and it agrees with the other one on substituting $X = f^{T}, Y = g$.
So, the short answer for why we can get rid of the transpose is that the inner product of vectors can be written in either order $f^{T}g=g^{T}f$. This is what @user2628206 is referring to about suppressing implicit transpose operations.

I was asked in the comments to explain how this turns a vector-matrix multiplication into a vector-vector multiplication, and whether this is some sort of trick.
We started with equation (2), which is an equation where both sides are row vectors. If I have two equal row vectors $v_1^{T} = v_2^{T}$, then for any column vector $x$ I can multiply both sides by $x$ and get $v_1^{T} x = v_2^{T} x$, which is an equation of scalars. To turn an equation of row vectors into an equation of numbers, all you have to do is multiply by a column vector.
When I multiply both sides by $\partial x$, this is exactly what I am doing, since $\partial x$ is a column vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$. This was necessary because equation (2) is an equation of row vectors and equation (37) is an equation of scalars if you set $X$ as a row vector and $Y$ as a column vector.
In fact, it is also possible to go in reverse. If I have two row vectors $v_1^{T}$ and $v_2^{T}$, and the equation $v_1^{T} x = v_2^{T}x$ holds for all column vectors $x$, then I can conclude that $v_1^{T} = v_2^{T}$. So it is possible to take multiple scalar equations, and conclude that a vector equation holds. (You probably know this even without realizing: if you see that each coordinate of two vectors are equal and conclude that the vectors are equal, you are deriving a vector equation from multiple scalar equations as a matter of routine.)

I was also asked to explain the meaning behind the replacement of $J_p$ with $\partial$, and the multiplication of both sides by $\partial x$.
To understand this, we have to understand what it means to write $J_p(f) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. Of course, it is not really possible to "divide" vectors in the same way we divide ordinary numbers.
The expression $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is just a notation to indicate the fact that $J_p(f)$ is a matrix that takes in the column vector $\partial x$ and returns (a linear approximation to) the column vector $\partial f$. The equation $\partial f = J_p(f) \cdot \partial x$ is what defines the Jacobian. We say $J_p(f) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ because this notation simplifies the equation to $\partial f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}{\partial x}$, which is a convenient form.
So, when you multiply $J_p(f)$ by $\partial x$, the result is (a linear approximation to) $\partial f$. This is what it means to replace $J_p$ with $\partial$: it means we multiplied on the right by $\partial x$.
This is always correct, on the assumption that there exists a matrix that takes $\partial x$ as input and gives a linear approximation to $\partial f$ as output. There are functions $f$ for which it is not possible to construct such a matrix. I should also be precise about how much error I am allowing in my approximations (hence the comment about little-o notation).

Finally, I was asked to explain if this answer relies on $X$ and $Y$ being vectors. The answer is not really, but it might require more linear algebra to deal with other cases.
The notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is used for a linear function that takes objects of the same type as $x$ to objects of the same type as $f$. In this particular case, both $x$ and $f$ are column vectors, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is a matrix.
It is possible (for example) for $x$ to be a matrix, and $X$ and $Y$ can be matrix valued functions that have input $x$. Then the identity still holds:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial XY}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial X}{\partial x}Y + X \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}.
\end{align}
It is also possible to multiply through by the matrix $\partial x$, and end up with a (first-order approximation) equation relating matrices:
\begin{align}
\partial (XY) = (\partial X)Y + X(\partial Y).
\end{align}
But it might not be obvious to you how to interpret $\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}$, which is a linear function that takes in a matrix and outputs a matrix. There is a certain type of tensor that takes in a matrix and output a matrix, and this is the type of object that $\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}$ is.

I think I see what you did. However, I am somewhat amazed that one can simply replace the $J_p$ with $\partial$ and remove the $\partial x$. This is kind of the reason, why your deduction works. The reason why I am amazed is because this turns a matrix-vector multiplication ($g^T J_p f$), which is a vector, into a vector-vector multiplication ($g^T \partial g$), which is a single value. This feels like some sort of black magic or even cheating. If you understand what I mean, can you elaborate on that?

Also, this trick is only possible if $X$ and $Y$ are (column) vectors instead of full matrices, is that right?

@Make42 In general the replacing '$J_p$' with '$\partial$' and removing the '$\partial x$' is not possible. There is trickery with limits going on below the surface here. In the above the equations of the form $\sum_{i \in I}\partial f_i =  \sum_{j \in J}\partial g_j$ are not actually true unless you add small correcting factors into play. Look up little o-notation for more info.

@user2628206: Is the answer from sotto_pover_cielo basically the same as what you would have written?

I've expanded the description. This answer is getting a bit long, so feel free to ask more questions if anything is unclear, and I can respond in a different answer.

(37) can be written more fully as
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}(XY) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}X)Y + X(\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}Y).$$
I will give a derivation of the version of (1) when $X$ and $Y$ are matrix valued functions of a vector $p$. This is the most general form of the product rule. I write $JX(p)$ instead of $J_pX$. Write $A(p) = X(p)Y(p)$. Then
\begin{align}
A(p + h) &= X(p + h)Y(p + h) \\
&= (X(p) + JX(p)h + o(h))(Y(p) + JY(p)h + o(h)) \\
&= X(p)Y(p) + (JX(p)h)Y(p) + X(p)(JY(p)h) + o(h).
\end{align}
Thus
$$JA(p)h = (JX(p)h)Y(p) + X(p)(JY(p)h).$$
This is the general result that encompasses (1) and (37). To get (37), you just put $h = e_j$. To get (1) use $X(p) = f(p)^T$, $Y(p) = g(p)$ to get
\begin{align}
JA(p)h &= (Jf(p)h)^Tg(p) + f(p)^TJg(p)h \\
&= g(p)^TJf(p)h + f(p)^TJg(p)h \\
&= (g(p)^TJf(p) + f(p)^TJg(p))h.
\end{align}
Hence
$$JA(p) = g(p)^TJf(p) + f(p)^TJg(p).$$


Why is (37) equivalent to your second formula? (Why is the H of the first summand of the RHS left of the Y?) 2. I do not see the connection between your second formula, (37) and (1). I would require a much more detailed step-by-step deduction in order to understand.


@Make42 I rewrote the answer. Now it is correct and answers all your questions. The key phrase here is "Frechet Derivative".
